# Can I change colors of image textures when applied in blender 2.8?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, color, vector-mapping

I'm in the middle of applying materials and textures to a project I'm working on.  I've found a lot of good textures and they work very well, but they are not the right color.  I've tried using the different nodes like hue and saturation and mix RGB and curves, but nothing turns out quite right.  For example I am applying a rust texture to a large barrel, and the image texture is a steel grey with rust, but would like base color to be a dark red.  I'm able to go into photoshop and adjust the colors of the texture file there to a degree.  Is there a way to do this while in blender?  I'm using blender 2.8 and rendering in cycles.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I don't know why you don't succeed, you should be able to do what you want with Hue Saturation, Bright Contrast or RGB Curves...

Comment: And to add - you can also use the same blend modes as in Photoshop (multiply, overlay, hue...) through the [Mix RGB node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/color/mix.html).

Comment: Maybe your problem is that the original picture is only black, white and grey? I've noticed this problem, it makes impossible to use Hue and other color nodes to change the colors, but as Jachym says it looks like plugging the image into the MixRGB does the trick

Comment: Thanks!  It looked like I had plugged something in to the wrong node.  *facepalm*